# How do I get intellisense for OpenGL calls?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I want something like this in Visual Studio 2010 with C++:
http://www.opentk.com/node/689

If there is no way to get this, is there at least a realtime API browser? Constantly copy pasting the function names into http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/ is getting tiring.

Comment: It's not clear what information you're looking for. Do you just want function prototypes, or are you looking for actual documentation?